# The Sims 3: Earn 10,000 Simoleons?

Tags: the-sims-3

In The Sims 3, one of my sims has the wish to "Earn 10,000 Simoleons". Even though she is at the top of the corporate career ladder, she doesn't make even close to that much.

Is there something I should do outside of her regular job to fulfill this wish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine this is a cumulative goal, not something that she has to do all at once.  Just keep at it and it will eventually be granted.

Short of that, the fastest way I've found to make money outside of careers is by writing novels.  Once you've mastered it, you can pump out a novel a day for an insane amount of royalties.

Comment: This is, in fact, a cumulative goal, and includes daily paychecks as well as bonuses (from raises) and successful chance cards / opportunities at work.

Comment: There should be some way to view progress towards the goal, though I'm not sure if that functionality was added in an xpac, part of Awesome Mod, or just willful misremembrance.

Comment: While hovering over the wish, an amount–either daily pay or progress towards the total, don't know yet which–of simoleons is displayed, without any mods.

Comment: It turned out it was indeed a cumulative goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use cheat codes to make money which makes the game lose all its potential and fun in my opinion.

Other than that, you can make money by selling things like paintings, novels, handmade stuff.

Comment: Actually, I think this opportunity can only be completed with regular (in this sim's case) office work, since neither holding meetings or selling books counted towards the total. I do have to agree on the cheat bit.

Comment: Hmm the oppurtunity just says "earn" so I assume it is ok to earn with any way. I play this game every single day kinda addicted and I completed lots of oppurtunities like this. As far as I remember, any way you make money must be counted but I may be wrong too :)

Answer (score 2):

Play the Real Estate game. Become a partner in all the shops and stores in your town. Every monday you can collect rent. After a few weeks of this save your money and buy out the properties. The money you collect from owned real estate is awesome. That 10,000 mark is only beginning, wait til they ask you to reach 100K, 500K, 1mil =)

You could also collect rocks, cut gems, etc but I like real estate cause you can do 1 rent run every week and pull in like 50K in 2hrs

Answer (score 1):

you could try to get money from the skills the sim or sims in the family have.
For example when you have an Artist in your family the artist could paint images and your Sim with the wish can sell it. You still get the money but it gets counted towards the Sim who sells the painting at the very end.

If you have enough time you could accept a part-time job as second income